USB audio interface causes pc power crash
I bought a usb audio interface and when I plug it into my computer it powers off.
It's an i5 desktop with 16gb ram having no issues This is the item ebay.com/itm/387095713148 I have other computers I can test it on yes

Can you provide some more information about your environment? Are you able to test it on more computers?

It's an i5 desktop with 16gb ram having no issues This is the item https://www.ebay.com/itm/387095713148 I have other computers I can test it on yes

Does the same thing happen on them?

I tried on another desktop and nothing happened when I plugged in the usb cable

Could it be that it works on the other machine because this machine can't provide the current it's trying to draw because there's already three hard drives installed on the machine that turns off when I plug in the usb cable

A computer may shut down if a USB device draws too much power. It sounds like your USB hub or motherboard has a fault in the power supply circuitry.
